# Simulate columns with flex, respecting page break in print styles

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to simulate columns with a flex grid in a print view?

The elements within that grid should break automatically from left to right column and start on top of left column when page breaks.

Same as "columns: 2" would do, but with flex instead of columns.

The magic print view:

[image]

Desktop view (which is no problem, so no questions for that):

[image]